# How can i get parameters from play store download link

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am currently developing a mobile app with react-native and this app contain a invitation code.

Store download link will have a invitation code parameter.

I want to get this parameter from downloaded apps via store download link.

How can i do this on react-native ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use Firebase Dynamic Links**

Firebase Invites makes it simple for users to send content to their friends, over both SMS and email, by ensuring that referral codes, recipe entries, or other shared content gets passed along with the invitation—no cutting-and-pasting required.

**Documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/**

How does it work?

You create a Dynamic Link either by using the Firebase console, using a REST API, iOS or Android Builder API, or by forming a URL by adding Dynamic Link parameters to a domain specific to your app. These parameters specify the links you want to open, depending on the user's platform and whether your app is installed.

When a user opens one of your Dynamic Links, if your app isn't yet installed, the user is sent to the Play Store / App Store to install your app (unless you specify otherwise), and your app will open. You can then retrieve the link that was passed to your app and handle the deep link as appropriate for your app.

**For react-native** use react-native-firebase https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-firebase
and 
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/links/reference/links